# How to add a list property to Entity Framework Code First model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm not sure how to best make this work for code-first entity-framework. I'd want to make sure that any changes to the list would modify the csv property. I would also want to make sure that any linq2sql queries would still work efficiently(-ish) using this approach.

**The Goal:**

```
public class Profile {
    public string Email {get;set;}

    // This has to save to the DB somehow.
    public IEnumerable<int> EmailAudienceTypes { get; set; } 
}
```

**Context:** 
Alright, ignore the obvious normalization problems you could complain about for this. In our company we have an AudienceType table that functions as a kind of enum. You pick one type from the list and store the chosen type using the type's id.  Everything from email addresses to user activities can be controlled with a AudienceTypeID. In the past we would have "EmailAudienceTypeId" as a property to mark the level of sharing to be used for that field. So that's the legacy code.

[image]

We have a chance for site refactor. They'd like to be able to select **multiple audiences** for each attribute now. Normalized solution would be terrible.

[image]

So I've got a kind of wacky solution in mind, but I'm not sure how to best make this work for code-first entity-framework. I'd want to make sure that any changes to the list would modify the csv property. I would also want to make sure that any linq2sql queries would still work efficiently(-ish) using this approach.

```
public List<int> EmailAudienceTypes {
            get {
                return EmailVisibleToRolesCsv.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                  .ToList();
            } }
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the normalized/link table approach?

Comment: @cALC Have to imagine this on a larger scale (There are a lot of attributes that need to be mapped). A profile could have 10 attributes. Could also have 25 other tables using this same AudienceType system. Having a normalized link table system would be too verbose.